# Android Studio how to get “OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues.” warning message *back*!

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tl;dr: how to "undo" an erroneous click on "Do not show again" in Android studio?

**

When I fire up Android Studio (installed using umake on Ubuntu 14.04) I used to get a warning message telling me to change my JDK from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK. I decided today to fix this and, accidentally, the first thing I managed to do was to click "don't show this warning again" on Studio :-/

So now I think I've fixed the problem, but given that there seems to be several competing ways of telling studio to use a given JDK (setting an environment variable, changing Ubuntu's default java etc) I now want to make sure that I've solved it so I want to make studio give me the warning back! Either that, or a way of determining precisely which of my javas studio is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `file` -> `Project Structure` -> `SDK Location` and make sure your JDK is pointing to the directory where the Oracle JDK is located instead of the OpenJDK.

Default paths for the OpenJDK

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

If you have used webupd8team's PPA to install Oracle Java, then the JDK path should be set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

[image: Set Oracle JDK, Android Studio]

Comment: @Yannick If this post helped you, please mark this as the answer to your question. ;)

Comment: It didn't answer the question, but it'll be the best I'll get :-)